# Swift: Cannot modify images in popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popup, uikit

Beginner swift-user here. I want to open a pop up connected to a seperate view controller (P2_Gift_Pop_Up) from the main view controller. To this end I include the following in a code snippet in my main view controller

```
let vc = P2_Gift_Pop_Up()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext 
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This starts running code in the popup window (a print statement works anyway), so so far, so good.

However, when I try to modify some elements in the view connected to the view controller I get a

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value. Here is the code in its entirety.

```
import UIKit

class P2_Gift_Pop_Up: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Slot1: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Slot1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Card 2 Red"), for: .normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Although I have (via another answer on this site) an understanding of what the msg means, I don't understand why I get it in this context, and how to fix it. It might also bear emphasis that although code starts running after the P2_Gift_Pop_Up call, the corresponding view is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to present your controller like this(you need to set your storyboard ID and then add this in identifier):

```
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your storyboard id") as! P2_Gift_Pop_Up
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Your app is crashing because of your button(Slot1) not have a memory so you need to present like above.

Comment: This generates the errormsg: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in AppDelegate

Comment: Have you added Storyboard ID?

Comment: Please replace your storyboard name with "main" and please add your controller storyboardID in (withIdentifier: "your storyboard id")

Comment: I updated the code in accordance with your change, went to the storyboard clicked the little yellow circle with a white square in it and added "P2GiftPopUpId"in the identity inspector and then replaces "your storyboard id" with "P2GiftPopUpId". But the same message remains.

Comment: Managed to piece together what I had to do with yours and duncans answers together. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@JogendarChoudhary told you what to do, but didn't really explain why.

When you create your `P2_Gift_Pop_Up` with

```
let vc = P2_Gift_Pop_Up()
```

You aren't initializing it properly. It doesn't get a chance to load it's views from it's XIB file/storyboard.

Assuming you have your view controller defined in your main app storyboard, you need to load the view controller from the storyboard.

You should add a unique identifier to your view controller in your storyboard, and then load it using that identifier. (Using the name of the class as the identifier is as good a choice as any.)

The `UIViewController` class has a property `storyboard` which will contain the storyboard from which it's loaded. Usually that's your app's main storyboard, and what you want. Thus:

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "P2_Gift_Pop_Up id") 
    as? P2_Gift_Pop_Up {
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext 
  present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
  print("error creating P2_Gift_Pop_Up")
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for the solution and the explanation!